# Magento 2 Send email to customer when import

Tags: magento2, importexport

Hello Magento Experts,

I would like to send email to customers when I am doing customer import on Magento 2.

Please help me to achieve this.

I found this is bug in Magento 2 here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10055

So I am planning to override Magento to write custom code to send a welcome email when doing the import.

I am going to override this model file in my custom module:

```
/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer-import-export/Model/Import/Customer.php function _saveCustomerEntities line no. 263.
```

Please let me know if this approach is correct.

Comment: Please add more details, what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can use this one: https://github.com/augustash/magento2-module-customer-import